# Drawing the glm decision boundary with ggplot's stat_smooth() function returns wrong line

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm, boundary

I want to plot the decision boundary after I fit a logistic regression model to my data.  I use ggplot and stat_smooth() function to define the decision boundary line. However the plot returned is wrong.  For a reproducible example, see below:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONSTRUCT THE DATA
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

X.1_Y.1 <- rnorm(1000, mean = 1.5, sd= 0.3)

X.2_Y.1 <- rnorm(1000, mean = 1.5, sd= 5)

X.1_Y.0 <- rnorm(99000, mean = 0, sd = 1)

X.2_Y.0 <- rnorm(99000, mean = 0, sd = 1)

data <- data.table(X.1 = c(X.1_Y.1 , X.1_Y.0),
                   X.2 = c(X.2_Y.1  , X.2_Y.0),
                   Y = c(rep(1, 1000) , rep(0, 99000 ))
                   )


#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# FIT A LOGISTIC MODEL ON THE DATA
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


model <- glm(Y ~ X.1 + X.2, data, family = "binomial")

summary(model)

#Call:
#  glm(formula = Y ~ ., family = "binomial", data = data)

#Deviance Residuals: 
#  Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#-1.6603  -0.1194  -0.0679  -0.0384   4.6263  

#Coefficients:
#  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#(Intercept) -6.04055    0.06636  -91.02   <2e-16 ***
#  X.1          1.60828    0.03854   41.73   <2e-16 ***
#  X.2          0.43272    0.01673   25.87   <2e-16 ***
#  ---
#  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

#(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

#Null deviance: 11200.3  on 99999  degrees of freedom
#Residual deviance:  8218.5  on 99997  degrees of freedom
#AIC: 8224.5


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DEFINE AND DRAW THE DECISION BOUNDARY
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# 0 = -6.04 + 1.61 * X.1 + 0.44 * X2 => X2 = 6.04/0.44 - 1.61/0.44 * X.1

setDT(data)


ggplot(data, aes(X.1, X.2, color = as.factor(Y))) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2) + 
   stat_smooth(formula = x.2 ~ 6.04/0.44 - (1.61/0.44) * X.1, color = "blue", size = 2) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_economist()
```

This returns the following plot:

[image]

You can easily see that the line drawn is wrong.  According to the formula X.2 should be 6.04/0.44 when X.1 = 0 which clearly is not the case in this plot.

Could you tell me where my code errs and how to correct it?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to plot a line on your graph that you fit yourself, you should not be using `stat_smooth`, you should be using `stat_function`. For example

```
ggplot(data, aes(X.1, X.2, color = as.factor(Y))) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2) + 
  stat_function(fun=function(x) {6.04/0.44 - (1.61/0.44) * x}, color = "blue", size = 2) +
  coord_equal()
```